# Stem cells and if they can correct a lack of apoptosis

Tags: stem-cells, apoptosis

If a cell ,call it C1 has no functioning apoptosis mechanism could a stem cell somehow be 'induced' to be like C1 , at least have the same genome as C1. Then use this stem cell 'duplicate' to 'restart' the apoptosis mechanisms in C1 or even replace C1? ( forgive any broadness or vagueness, I'm trying to be specific)

Comment: If I understand what you're asking (which I'm not sure I do...), no, it's not possible. Cells don't transfer their genomes between each other, so any defects or advantages in one cell won't transfer to a neighboring cell. The only way genes are transferred is down a lineage, with the genome of a parent cell being replicated and passed on to daughter cells.

Comment: But can a stem cell be made to 'copy' the genome of a cell with no apoptosis mechanism. Or at least be almost identical to the damaged cell?

Comment: Once you copy the genome of a cell into another cell (something that has to happen in the lab, a cell just can't "pick up" a neighboring cell's genes), it becomes a clone of that cell, and loses whatever properties it had before. So, if you have a cancer cell with no functioning apoptosis mechanisms, and copy its genome into a stem cell, the stem cell becomes a cancer cell, and no longer has the properties of "stem-ness".

Comment: I think you might have a fundamental misunderstanding of what stem cells are, and what they can do. Given the proper chemical pushes, a stem cell can differentiate into nearly any cell type in the body. However, its DNA remains the same - it's just gene *expression* that changes. Like I said earlier, genomic changes (mutations) cannot be transfered from one cell to the one next to it.

Comment: Can a stem cell's gene expression be made to be like some damaged cell's gene expression that has no apoptosis mechanism.

Comment: No, unless you make the exact same genetic changes in the stem cell as occurred in the damaged cell. Once you do that, it's no longer a stem cell. In fact, there's no point in starting with a stem cell, because you're not taking advantage of any of its unique properties.

Comment: Maybe you should step back and explain the bigger picture - what exactly are you trying to do? I think you're focusing too narrowly on one particular thing which doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: I'm trying to research or figure out if there are useful ways to reactivate an apoptosis mechanism in a damaged cell. If a cell's gene expression has been damaged or distorted by many aquired mutations and it's apoptosis processes aren't functioning maybe if the cell's gene expression can be somehow 'reset' to when it didn't have mutations it's apoptosis mechanism would 'work' again.

Comment: That would be nice, but unfortunately it's impossible, at least with today's knowledge and methods. It takes a lot of mutations to completely knock out all mechanisms of apoptosis, and along with that a ton of other mutations occur, as well. The genome of a cancer cell is pretty screwed up. There's just no way to repair it, you've just got to kill the cell and start over. Incidentally, this is one reason why cells have so many different ways to commit suicide - as they start accumulating all these mutations, if they can detect them, they take themselves out of circulation.

Comment: And these aren't just nice little point mutations, either - entire chromosomes get duplicated, chopped up, rearranged, amplified, etc. There's no template present to "start from scratch."

Comment: If it takes a lot of mutations to shut down all mechanisms of apoptosis does that mean apoptosis 'shut-down' doesn't occur that much? If a cancerous cell is extremely 'screwed up' why can't the immune system detect it? Do cancer cells emit some chemicals that can mask it?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is **no.**  There is no method currently known whereby we could get a stem cell to transfer its genome to a cancerous cell and thus get its apoptosis mechanism functioning again.  It's just not that easy to get a genome transfered - destroying the defective copy of the genome which is stored in the nucleus and getting a new copy of the entire genome into the same.

Remember that to transfer almost anything (except small non-polar molecules) in and out of the cell, you need highly specialized transporters (ie., ion channels, Na+/glucose pumps).  This is particularly true of large molecules like glucose and sucrose (plants). But even those molecules are ***extremely*** small compared to an entire chromosome, for which there is nothing even close to a transporter.  It would therefore be impossible to get the chromosome into the cell.

But *even if you could,* you have yet another hurdle: you have to get the new chromosomes into the nucleus... and that only after having destroyed the original genome in Cell 1, without making the environment in the nucleus toxic for the new genome (ie., CAD activity...)  This represents innumerable challenges, including the fact that you're going to need to alter the nuclear membrane to allow the entry of a massive macromolecule, without impeding the function of the cell...  The problems, unfortunately, go on and on.

**TL;DR:**  Nice idea, and would be really cool if it worked, but it has way, *way,* ***way*** too may complexities and insurmountable hurdles to be even remotely workable.

---

#### Sources:

- Lemoine R. 2000. Sucrose transporters in plants: update on function and structure. *Biomembranes* 1465 (1–2): 246-262.